# cocoa: how to create single column table view with checkboxes and labels

Tags: xcode, cocoa, checkbox, label, tableview

I have a fixed number of text items I want to display with checkboxes to select/deselect in a cocoa tableview.  Exactly like a listbox of items with checkboxes in Microsoft MFC.

If I drop the section labels and checkboxes into the TableView they don't seem to belong to the tableview.  Note: the labels are to divide/designate the sections for the checkbox items.

What are the correct steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `CustomCell` class: take a `NSTextField` and `NSButton`(for checkbox)-

> set UIButton state in IB:

```
for default state - set non selected image.
 for selected state - set selected image.
```

> In CustomCell.m file

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [checkBoxBTN setSelected:selected];
}
```

> you can do this in also `cellForRowAtIndex` method in your `tableView` class.
>   your table data source should be a `ModelClass` or a dictionary with two keys like title and its state(selected/nonSelected). 
>   In `didSelectAtIndexPath` method you need to update your dictionary like:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic = [yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSNumber *state = [dic valueForKey:@"state"];
[dic setValue:![state boolValue]];
```

> You need to modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method to show prev selected/nonSelected state

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic = [yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSNumber *state = [dic valueForKey:@"state"];
cell.title = [dic valueForKey:@"title"];
[cell.checkBoxBtn setSelected:[state boolValue]];
```

> Edit
>   To create Label:

```
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 17)];
    [textField setStringValue:@"My Label"];
    [textField setBezeled:NO];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setEditable:NO];
    [textField setSelectable:NO];
    [cell addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: There is no `UILabel` in Cocoa. Cocoa basically means OS X.

Comment: Do this to create Label: I have Edited my Ans

Comment: I'm not clear on several items (I'm new to Objective-C and Cocoa):

Per, "You can make a CustomCell class: take a UILabel and UIButton(for checkbox)-"

what exactly do you mean by take a UILabel and UIButton?  Can you provide an example of this class?

Also I thought it was to be a NSLabel and NSButton? 

Per, "You need to modify your cellForRowAtIndexPath Method to show prev selected/nonSelected state"

Why previous, and method of what class?  
How does one set the title of each row's Checkbox?

Your example seems to be missing some steps or descriptions, such as what to do in the IB.
Thanks.

Comment: you can use NSTextField instead of UILabel. And set NSButton propery in Interface Builder file as its state( a Button has different states- defaule,selected,highlighted,...). So you can use default state as nonSelected of your Button (There are different property for Button State like- Title,BackgroundImage,Image) So you have to set image property for default and selected state.

Comment: Can you provide an example of setting individual checkbox titles programmatically?  What I'm aiming for is a single column of checkboxes with text/titles to the right of each, but also in the same column are interspersed Labels that serve to separate/delineate vertical sections or groups of checkboxes.